# Why SwiftUI MagnificationGesture is jumpy?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I testing out how the MagnificationGesture works and have the following code that somewhat works (but it's very choppy!)

```
struct ImageOpacityView: View {
    @Binding var opacity: Double
    @Binding var image: Image
    
    @State var magScale: CGFloat = 1

    var magnificationGesture: some Gesture {
        MagnificationGesture().onChanged { gesture in
            self.magScale = gesture
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        self.image
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .opacity(opacity / 100)
            .gesture(self.magnificationGesture)
            .scaleEffect(self.magScale)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var opacity: Double = 50
    @State var image = Image(systemName: "photo.fill")
    
    var body: some View {
        ImageOpacityView(opacity: self.$opacity, image: self.$image)
    }
}
```

It's just a simple zoom effect that I'm looking for that can be combined with other stuff such as opacity change, and drag gesture, so far all the examples I found around here are either not smooth while the pinch is happening...

I appreciate if anyone can guide me in the correct direction...

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62730061/12299030?

Answer (score 0):

This code in theory should work! But after a lot of struggling with it I figured that the reason that the gesture is jumpy is because of the order of operations that I'm doing on the image. Moving the `.gesture(self.magnificationGesture)` all the way down did fix the jumping issue!

```
struct ImageOpacityView: View {
    @Binding var opacity: Double
    @Binding var image: Image
    
    @State var magScale: CGFloat = 1

    var magnificationGesture: some Gesture {
        MagnificationGesture().onChanged { gesture in
            self.magScale = gesture
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        self.image
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .opacity(opacity / 100)
            .scaleEffect(self.magScale)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .gesture(self.magnificationGesture)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var opacity: Double = 50
    @State var image = Image(systemName: "photo.fill")
    
    var body: some View {
        ImageOpacityView(opacity: self.$opacity, image: self.$image)
    }
}
```