# How to show zooming process in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on an app that enables a user to select emojis. Once one or more emoji(s) is/are selected (indicated by a blue border), the zoom gesture should zoom in only on the selected emojis. If no emoji is selected, the entire document should be zoomed into.

However, the zooming process for selected emojis is not shown during a zooming gesture. Instead, only the status once the gesture is completed is displayed (see GIF).

[image]

Please find the code below:

EmojiArtDocumentView.swift:

```
struct EmojiArtDocumentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var document: EmojiArtDocument

    let defaultEmojiFontSize: CGFloat = 40

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            documentBody
            palette
        }
    }

    var documentBody: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Color.white
                .overlay(
                    OptionalImage(uiImage: document.backgroundImage)
                        .scaleEffect(zoomScale)
                        .position(convertFromEmojiCoordinates((0,0), in: geometry))
                )
                .gesture(doubleTapToZoom(in: geometry.size).exclusively(before: tapToDeselectAllEmojis()))
                if document.backgroundImageFetchStatus == .fetching {
                    ProgressView().scaleEffect(2)
                } else {
                    ForEach(document.emojis) { emoji in
                        Text(emoji.text)
                        .font(.system(size: fontSize(for: emoji)))
                        .border(Color.blue, width: selectedEmojis.contains(emoji) ? 2 : 0)
                        .scaleEffect(zoomScale)
                        .position(position(for: emoji, in: geometry))
                        .gesture(selectionGesture(on: emoji).simultaneously(with: longPressToDelete(on: emoji).simultaneously(with: selectedEmojis.contains(emoji) ? panEmojiGesture() : nil)))
                    }
                }
            }
            .clipped()
            .onDrop(of: [.plainText, .url, .image], isTargeted: nil) { providers, location in
                drop(providers: providers, at: location, in: geometry)
            }
            .gesture(panGesture().simultaneously(with: zoomGesture()))
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Drag and Drop

    private func drop(providers: [NSItemProvider], at location: CGPoint, in geometry: GeometryProxy) -> Bool {
        var found = providers.loadObjects(ofType: URL.self) { url in
            document.setBackground(.url(url.imageURL))
        }
        if !found {
            found = providers.loadObjects(ofType: UIImage.self) { image in
                if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
                    document.setBackground(.imageData(data))
                }
            }
        }
        if !found {
            found = providers.loadObjects(ofType: String.self) { string in
                if let emoji = string.first, emoji.isEmoji {
                    document.addEmoji(
                        String(emoji),
                        at: convertToEmojiCoordinates(location, in: geometry),
                        size: defaultEmojiFontSize / zoomScale
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        return found
    }

    // MARK: - Positioning/Sizing Emoji

    private func position(for emoji: EmojiArtModel.Emoji, in geometry: GeometryProxy) -> CGPoint {
        if selectedEmojis.contains(emoji) {
            return convertFromEmojiCoordinates((emoji.x + Int(gestureEmojiPanOffset.width), emoji.y + Int(gestureEmojiPanOffset.height)), in: geometry)
        } else {
            return convertFromEmojiCoordinates((emoji.x, emoji.y), in: geometry)
        }
    }

    private func fontSize(for emoji: EmojiArtModel.Emoji) -> CGFloat {
        CGFloat(emoji.size)
    }

    private func convertToEmojiCoordinates(_ location: CGPoint, in geometry: GeometryProxy) -> (x: Int, y: Int) {
        let center = geometry.frame(in: .local).center
        let location = CGPoint(
            x: (location.x - panOffset.width - center.x) / zoomScale,
            y: (location.y - panOffset.height - center.y) / zoomScale
        )
        return (Int(location.x), Int(location.y))
    }

    private func convertFromEmojiCoordinates(_ location: (x: Int, y: Int), in geometry: GeometryProxy) -> CGPoint {
        let center = geometry.frame(in: .local).center
        return CGPoint(
            x: center.x + CGFloat(location.x) * zoomScale + panOffset.width,
            y: center.y + CGFloat(location.y) * zoomScale + panOffset.height
        )
    }

    // MARK: - Zooming

    @State private var steadyStateZoomScale: CGFloat = 1
    @GestureState private var gestureZoomScale: CGFloat = 1
    @GestureState private var gestureZoomScaleEmoji: CGFloat = 1

    private var zoomScale: CGFloat {
        steadyStateZoomScale * gestureZoomScale
    }

    private func zoomGesture() -> some Gesture {
        if selectedEmojis.isEmpty {
            return MagnificationGesture()
                .updating($gestureZoomScale) { latestGestureScale, gestureZoomScale, _ in
                    gestureZoomScale = latestGestureScale
                }
                .onEnded { gestureScaleAtEnd in
                    steadyStateZoomScale *= gestureScaleAtEnd
                }
        } else {
            return MagnificationGesture()
                .updating($gestureZoomScaleEmoji) { latestGestureScale, gestureZoomScaleEmoji, _ in
                    gestureZoomScaleEmoji = latestGestureScale
                }
                .onEnded { finalGestureScale in
                    for emoji in selectedEmojis {
                        document.scaleEmoji(emoji, by: finalGestureScale)
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private func doubleTapToZoom(in size: CGSize) -> some Gesture {
        TapGesture(count: 2)
            .onEnded {
                withAnimation {
                    zoomToFit(document.backgroundImage, in: size)
                }
            }
    }

    private func zoomToFit(_ image: UIImage?, in size: CGSize) {
        if let image = image, image.size.width > 0, image.size.height > 0, size.width > 0, size.height > 0  {
            let hZoom = size.width / image.size.width
            let vZoom = size.height / image.size.height
            steadyStatePanOffset = .zero
            steadyStateZoomScale = min(hZoom, vZoom)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Panning

    @State private var steadyStatePanOffset: CGSize = CGSize.zero
    @GestureState private var gesturePanOffset: CGSize = CGSize.zero
    @GestureState private var gestureEmojiPanOffset: CGSize = CGSize.zero

    private var panOffset: CGSize {
        (steadyStatePanOffset + gesturePanOffset) * zoomScale
    }

    private func panGesture() -> some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .updating($gesturePanOffset) { latestDragGestureValue, gesturePanOffset, _ in
                gesturePanOffset = latestDragGestureValue.translation / zoomScale
            }
            .onEnded { finalDragGestureValue in
                steadyStatePanOffset = steadyStatePanOffset + (finalDragGestureValue.translation / zoomScale)
            }
    }

    private func panEmojiGesture() -> some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .updating($gestureEmojiPanOffset) { latestDragGestureValue, gestureEmojiPanOffset, _ in
                gestureEmojiPanOffset = latestDragGestureValue.distance / zoomScale
            }
            .onEnded { finalDragGestureValue in
                for emoji in selectedEmojis {
                    document.moveEmoji(emoji, by: finalDragGestureValue.distance / zoomScale)
                }
            }
    }

    // MARK: - Selecting/deselecting emojis

    @State private var selectedEmojisId = Set<Int>()

    private var selectedEmojis: Set<EmojiArtModel.Emoji> {
        var selectedEmojis = Set<EmojiArtModel.Emoji>()
        for id in selectedEmojisId {
            selectedEmojis.insert(document.emojis.first(where: {$0.id == id})!)
        }
        return selectedEmojis
    }

    private func selectionGesture(on emoji: EmojiArtModel.Emoji) -> some Gesture {
        TapGesture()
            .onEnded {
                withAnimation {
                    selectedEmojisId.toggleMembership(of: emoji.id)
                }
            }
    }

    private func tapToDeselectAllEmojis() -> some Gesture {
        TapGesture()
            .onEnded {
                withAnimation {
                    selectedEmojisId = []
                }
            }
    }

    // MARK: - Deleting emojis

    private func longPressToDelete(on emoji: EmojiArtModel.Emoji) -> some Gesture {
        LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1.2)
            .onEnded { LongPressStateAtEnd in
                if let index = selectedEmojisId.firstIndex(of: emoji.id) {
                    selectedEmojisId.remove(at: index)
                }
                document.removeEmoji(emoji)
            }
    }

    // MARK: - Palette

    var palette: some View {
        ScrollingEmojisView(emojis: testEmojis)
            .font(.system(size: defaultEmojiFontSize))
    }

    let testEmojis = "⚽️⌚️❤️⛔️❌❓✅⚠️➕➖️"
}

struct ScrollingEmojisView: View {
    let emojis: String

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(emojis.map { String($0) }, id: \.self) { emoji in
                    Text(emoji)
                        .onDrag { NSItemProvider(object: emoji as NSString) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EmojiArtDocument.swift:

```
class EmojiArtDocument: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var emojiArt: EmojiArtModel {
        didSet {
            if emojiArt.background != oldValue.background {
                fetchBackgroundImageDataIfNecessary()
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        emojiArt = EmojiArtModel()
    }

    var emojis: [EmojiArtModel.Emoji] { emojiArt.emojis }
    var background: EmojiArtModel.Background { emojiArt.background }

    // MARK: - Background

    @Published var backgroundImage: UIImage?
    @Published var backgroundImageFetchStatus = BackgroundImageFetchStatus.idle

    enum BackgroundImageFetchStatus {
        case idle
        case fetching
    }

    private func fetchBackgroundImageDataIfNecessary() {
        backgroundImage = nil
        switch emojiArt.background {
        case .url(let url):
            // fetch the url
            backgroundImageFetchStatus = .fetching
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    if self?.emojiArt.background == EmojiArtModel.Background.url(url) {
                        self?.backgroundImageFetchStatus = .idle
                        if imageData != nil {
                            self?.backgroundImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        case .imageData(let data):
            backgroundImage = UIImage(data: data)
        case .blank:
            break
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Intent(s)

    func setBackground(_ background: EmojiArtModel.Background) {
        emojiArt.background = background
    }

    func addEmoji(_ emoji: String, at location: (x: Int, y: Int), size: CGFloat) {
        emojiArt.addEmoji(emoji, at: location, size: Int(size))
    }

    func moveEmoji(_ emoji: EmojiArtModel.Emoji, by offset: CGSize) {
        if let index = emojiArt.emojis.index(matching: emoji) {
            emojiArt.emojis[index].x += Int(offset.width)
            emojiArt.emojis[index].y += Int(offset.height)
        }
    }

    func scaleEmoji(_ emoji: EmojiArtModel.Emoji, by scale: CGFloat) {
        if let index = emojiArt.emojis.index(matching: emoji) {
            emojiArt.emojis[index].size = Int((CGFloat(emojiArt.emojis[index].size) * scale).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero))
        }
    }

    func removeEmoji(_ emoji: EmojiArtModel.Emoji) {
        if let index = emojiArt.emojis.firstIndex(of: emoji) {
            emojiArt.emojis.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I show the zooming process?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Look into `GeometryEffect` and `Animatable`

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62730061/12299030?